# Removing Multiple Lines after a specific word using Python

Tags: python, replace

I want to remove the last section of an article (i.e. References section) in a .txt file using Python. By "the whole section" I mean everything after the word "References":

[image: References Section]

Is there a way to remove all the content after the word "References" using regex or any other methods?

I have tried the following code, however, it only removes the first line after the word "References":

```
input_file = open("remove.txt", 'r', encoding= 'utf-8')
prev_line = False
lines =[]
for line in input_file:
    if not prev_line:
        lines.append(line)
    prev_line=False
    if "References" in line:
       prev_line=True
input_file.close()

input_file = open("input.txt", 'w')
for line in lines:
     input_file.write(line)
input_file.close()
```

Thank you

Comment: Remove `prev_line=False` before `if "References" in line:`

Comment: Do you want to truncate the line with `References`, or do you want to keep the whole line?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It doesn't make a difference actually. I just don't need the content following "References"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! I just removed `prev_line=False` and it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can read in the whole file using `read`.

```
text = input_file.read()
```

`find` is a string method to locate a substring. We can then use string slicing to select only everything before the desired word, `"References"` in this case

```
ans = text[:text.find("References")]
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Very good point, changed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Nice and clean. I'd pick this as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `prev_line=False` before `if "References" in line:`, because it will revert the `prev_line` value to the original `False` one, and the `if not prev_line: lines.append(line)` will get executed for all the lines below the line containing `References` but the one immediately below it.

So, you can use

```py
with open("remove.txt", 'r', encoding= 'utf-8') as input_file:
    prev_line = False
    lines = []
    for line in input_file:
        if not prev_line:
            lines.append(line)
        if "References" in line:
           prev_line=True

with open("input.txt", 'w') as input_file:
    for line in lines:
        input_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `in-place filtering` option of [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) module:

```
import fileinput

fin = fileinput.input('remove.txt', inplace=True)
for line in fin:
    if "References" in line:
        fin.close()
    else:
        print(line, end="")
```